# How to get index 0 of a php substring

Tags: php, explode, substr

Hie I have the below code. It works fine but i have a feeling it smells, is there a better way to write it than this. The objective is to get '58a9a55e1c54f'.

```
$value = 'songs/initial/58a9a55e1c54f.flac';

$test = substr($value, 16);
$test = explode(".",$test);
$finalResult = $test[0];
```

Comment: Belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work for any arbitrary /-delimited path name followed by a . separated string, as long as the string doesn't contain a /:

`$value = 'songs/initial/58a9a55e1c54f.flac';
$test = explode(".",end(explode("/",$value)));
$finalResult = $test[0];`